# Using DoFn multiple Times in Google Dataflow 1.9.0 in Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

I want to make one part of my Pipeline dependent on dynamic input to the Pipeline creation process. My question is, what is the recommendend way to do so?

If i have following (reduced) code:

```
public static void createPipeline(){
  Pipeline p = TestPipeline.create();
  p.apply(new Source()).apply(new DoFunction());
  p.apply(new AnotherSource()).apply(new DoFunction());
  p.run;
}
```

now the DoFunction should be a parameter. 
Should I instantiate it once and pass it to the function createPipeline, or should I use a Class Parameter and instantiate it?
Version with instantiated Function:

```
public static void createPipeline(DoFn dofn){
  Pipeline p = TestPipeline.create();
  p.apply(new Source()).apply(dofn);
  p.apply(new AnotherSource()).apply(dofn);
  p.run;
}
```

Version with class-parameter:

```
public static void createPipeline(Class<?> fnClass){
  Pipeline p = TestPipeline.create();
  p.apply(new Source()).apply(fnClass.newInstance());
  p.apply(new AnotherSource()).apply(fnClass.newInstance());
  p.run;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for passing a `Class` - you can just pass the `DoFn`.

```java
public static void createPipeline(DoFn<Foo, Baz> dofn) {
  Pipeline pipeline = TestPipeline.create();

  pipeline
      .apply(Read.from(new Source()))
      .apply(ParDo.of(dofn));

  pipeline
      .apply(Read.from(new AnotherSource()))
      .apply(ParDo.of(dofn));

  pipeline.run();
}
```

You can even pass the fully instantiated `ParDo.of(doFn)` transform and apply it multiple times.

If you are actually not going to use the `PCollection` returned from the `ParDo` then you can also just flatten the inputs together.